# Python Quantlib G2 calibration with negative interest

Tags: programming, quantlib, interest

I am currently calibrating the G2++ in Python with Quantlib in negative interest rate environments with cap volatilities. Unfortunately, this does not work as intended and I get error messages:RuntimeError: strike + displacement (-0.00425602 + 0) must be non-negative.

According to Brigo & Mercurio (2006), however, negative interest rates are generally possible in G2++. Is there a trick here or does anyone have experience with this adjustment?

Thank you very much! Please find attached the code. I define yield_curves as list of quantlib yield_curves for serveral points of time and cap_vols_list as quantlib QuoteHandle elements.

final_results = []

for i in range(len(yield_curves)-183, len(yield_curves)-182):
curve_date, ts_handle = yield_curves[i]
cap_date, quotes = cap_vols_list[i]

```
# Check for same dates
if curve_date == cap_date:
    ql.Settings.instance().evaluationDate = curve_date

    # Setup Model and Optimization
    model = ql.G2(ts_handle)
    optimization_method = ql.LevenbergMarquardt(1e-8, 1e-8, 1e-8)
    end_criteria = ql.EndCriteria(1000, 500, 1e-8, 1e-8, 1e-8)
    yts = ts_handle
    index = ql.Euribor6M(ts_handle)


    # Setup Cap Helpers and Pricing Engine
    helpers = [ql.CapHelper(i, j, index, ql.Annual, ql.Actual360(), False, yts) for i, j in zip(periods, quotes)]       # Hier kann auch ql.Semiannual verwendet wreden
    for h, i in zip(helpers, quotes):
        h.setPricingEngine(ql.TreeCapFloorEngine(model, 20))

    # Model Calibration
    model.calibrate(helpers, optimization_method, end_criteria)

    # Empty List for results
    results = []

    # Calculate Model Vola
    for i, helper in enumerate(helpers):
        maturity = periods[i]
        market_vol = quotes[i].value()
        model_value = helper.modelValue()
        model_vol = helper.impliedVolatility(model_value, 1e-6, 300, 0.0, 2.0)
        # Calculate Error
        percent_diff = (model_vol - market_vol) / market_vol * 100

        results.append([curve_date, maturity, market_vol, model_vol, percent_diff])

    # Append Results
    final_results.extend(results)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using **normal vols** should work (default is shiftedLN with 0 shift in Quantlib). Alternatively use a shift parameter. For example:

```
usd3mcurve=ql.YieldTermStructureHandle(ql.FlatForward(2,ql.UnitedStates(0),-0.05,ql.Actual360()))
model=ql.G2(usd3mcurve)
optimization_method = ql.LevenbergMarquardt(1e-8, 1e-8, 1e-8)
end_criteria = ql.EndCriteria(1000, 500, 1e-8, 1e-8, 1e-8)
periods = [ql.Period('1y'),ql.Period('2y'),ql.Period('5y'),ql.Period('7y'),ql.Period('10Y'),ql.Period('15Y')]
quotes = [ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(0.0045)),ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(0.0055)),ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(0.0065)),
          ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(0.0055)),ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(0.0035)),ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(0.0025))]
index = ql.USDLibor(ql.Period('3m'),usd3mcurve)
helpers = [ql.CapHelper(i, j, index, ql.Quarterly, ql.Actual360(), False, usd3mcurve,0,ql.Normal) for i,j in zip(periods,quotes)]
for h in helpers:
    h.setPricingEngine(ql.TreeCapFloorEngine(model,20))
model.calibrate(helpers,optimization_method,end_criteria)
print(model.params())

model_vols=[]
for h in helpers:
    model_vols.append(h.impliedVolatility(h.modelValue(),1e-5,50,0,4))
print(model_vols)
```

gives parameters

```
[ 0.241215; 0.00715896; 0.243035; 0.00408839; -0.508568 ]
```

and vols:

```
[0.005542885387877183, 0.005189063505819368, 0.0044364313964000875, 0.004039502609889546, 0.003556074388616398, 0.002984907583591529]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick reply. With this adjustment, the optimization also works with negative interest rates, but the model implied volas for caps deviate extremely from the market implied (they didn`t before in non-negativ interest scenarios). Is there a reason for this?              helpers = [ql.CapHelper(i, j, index, ql.Semiannual, ql.Actual360(), False, yts, 0, ql.Normal) for i, j in zip(periods, quotes)]
        for h, i in zip(helpers, quotes):
            h.setPricingEngine(ql.TreeCapFloorEngine(model, 20))

Comment: did u switch your original market vols to equivalent normal (bp) vols as well?

Comment: I use the normal Vols quoted by Refinitiv workspace. There is the selection between Lognormal Vol, Normal Vol and Shifted Lognormal. So e.g. currently for 1Y Cap 92.01 bps. In the code I divide it by 100: for index, row in cap_vols_data.iterrows():
    # Extract the date
    cap_date = ql.Date(row['Date'].day, row['Date'].month, row['Date'].year)

    # Extract the Cap Volatilities and divide by 100
    cap_vols = {str(period.length()) + 'Y': row[str(period.length()) + 'Y'] / 100 for period in periods}

Comment: normal vols are quoted in bps, so in code should be 0.009201 (which is 0.9201%). I'll edit my answer so u can check that the calibration works for -ve rates

Comment: Thanks! I get almost perfect results for non-negativ environments (0.02% average error) but about 35% error compared to market vols in negativ interest case.
        helpers = [ql.CapHelper(i, j, index, ql.Semiannual, ql.Actual360(), False, yts, 0, ql.Normal) for i, j in zip(periods, quotes)]
        for h, i in zip(helpers, quotes):
            h.setPricingEngine(ql.TreeCapFloorEngine(model, 20))
        model.calibrate(helpers, optimization_method, end_criteria)

Comment: This is the way I calculate the model_vol: # Calculate Model Vola
        for i, helper in enumerate(helpers):
            maturity = periods[i]
            market_vol = quotes[i].value()
            model_value = helper.modelValue()
            model_vol = helper.impliedVolatility(model_value, 1e-6, 300, 0.0, 2.0)
            # Calculate Error
            percent_diff = (model_vol - market_vol) / market_vol * 100

Comment: I don't think the -ve rates should impact the calibration while using normal vols. I've edited my dummy code above and get similar results either with +ve or -ve rates.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151347/discussion-between-marc157-and-user35980).